# Comparar fechas JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente función en JS:

```
const DATE_REGEX = /^\d{4}([\-/.])(0?[1-9]|1[1-2])\1(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])$/
const CURRENT_YEAR = new Date().getFullYear()
const DATE = new Date()

const validateDate = (birthDate) => {
    /* Comprobar formato dd/mm/yyyy, que el no sea mayor de 12 y los días mayores de 31 */
    if (!birthDate.match(DATE_REGEX)) {
        return false
    }

    /* Comprobar los días del mes */
    const year = parseInt(birthDate.split('/')[0])
    const month = parseInt(birthDate.split('/')[1])
    const day = parseInt(birthDate.split('/')[2])

    const monthDays = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate()

    /* Comprobar que el año no sea superior al actual*/
    if (year > CURRENT_YEAR) {
        return false
    }

    if (day > monthDays) {
        return false
    }
    
    // Aquí intento comparar fechas para que la fecha que se reciba como argumento no sea mayor a hoy, osea solo como fecha maxima hoy
    let dateFormat = DATE.getFullYear() + "/" + (DATE.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + DATE.getDate();
    console.log(dateFormat);

    let dates = new Date(birthDate);
    dates.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    console.log(dates.setHours(0,0,0,0));

    if(dates > dateFormat){
        return false
    }
    // Aquí termina mi comparación   

    return true
}
```

El argumento es una fecha que paso formateada como aaaa/mm/dd, desde un campo en un formulario, son registros a una base de datos. No me muestra ningún error en consola, pero si permite fechas mayores

Replique por fuera:

```
const date = new Date();
var dateFormat = date.getFullYear() + "/" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date.getDate()
console.log(dateFormat);

const dates = new Date('2023/03/01');
dates.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(dates);

if(dates > date){
    console.log("S");
} else {
    console.log("N");
}
```

Funciona en la replica pero en el código principal, intente hacer algo con Date().getDay() pero me regresa un integer que no lo puedo comparar con el día en el argumento formateado:

```
new Date().getDay() = 3 (es miercoles, 0 es domingo . . .)
// Pero si un miercoles como hoy es 2023/02/01, no entra en esa condicion "01 > 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

La comparación que tienes entre dates y dateFormat es comparación entre un `Date` y un `string` (que probablemente no te de los resultados esperados).

Puedes compararlo con dos `Date` así:

```js
const DATE_REGEX = /^\d{4}([\-/.])(0?[1-9]|1[1-2])\1(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])$/
const CURRENT_YEAR = new Date().getFullYear()
const DATE = new Date()

const validateDate = (birthDate) => {
    /* Comprobar formato dd/mm/yyyy, que el no sea mayor de 12 y los días mayores de 31 */
    if (!birthDate.match(DATE_REGEX)) {
        return false
    }

    /* Comprobar los días del mes */
    const year = parseInt(birthDate.split('/')[0])
    const month = parseInt(birthDate.split('/')[1])
    const day = parseInt(birthDate.split('/')[2])

    const monthDays = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate()

    /* Comprobar que el año no sea superior al actual*/
    if (year > CURRENT_YEAR) {
        return false
    }

    if (day > monthDays) {
        return false
    }
    
    // Aquí intento comparar fechas para que la fecha que se reciba como argumento no sea mayor a hoy, osea solo como fecha maxima hoy
    const now = new Date();

    let dates = new Date(birthDate);
    if(dates > now){
        return false
    }
    // Aquí termina mi comparación   

    return true
}

console.log("Fecha pasada es valida?", validateDate("2023/01/01"));
console.log("Fecha futura es valida?", validateDate("2040/12/31"));
```

Comment: Hola @Pipe, me gusta tu respuesta, pero tiene un problema, que no es de la respuesta en sí, sino que es coyuntural, a partir del 04/01/2023... la ejecución de tu respuesta va a dar *true, true*, podrías modificar eso para que si alguien accede a tu respuesta en un futuro, verifique que esta es válida?.

Comment: De donde sacas esa conclusión? Mi codigo valida que la fecha sea menor que el dia que se corre el código... Tampoco entiendo lo de "coyuntural" jejejeje. No hay ninguna condición para la fecha específica que mencionas

Comment: tu código hace lo que tiene que hacer, la demostración, osea **console.log("Fecha futura es valida?", validateDate("2023/03/01"));**, nos devuelve false... hoy, mañana devolverá true, por eso lo de coyuntural.

Comment: Mil perdones, se me metió en la cabeza que habías comparado fecha actual con 3 de Febrero, por eso te decía que mañana iba a fallar, va a fallar el 2 de Marzo ("2023/03/01"), es una pavada, pero me parece que al que pruebe tu respuesta después de esa fecha, tal vez se le escape el detalle, y crea que es incorrecta.

Comment: Ok, ya entiendo tu punto, acabo de modificar la respuesta para que la fecha futura sea aun más futura XD

Comment: Genio!!!! espero no haberte molestado!!